# How to iterate in python visitor of antlr

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to create objects using visitors of the python target. For the following grammar rule:

```
prog : stat+ ;
```

I have this visitor code for creating the corresponding objects:

```
def visitProg(self, ctx:ExprParser.ProgContext):
    stat_list = []
    for s in ctx.stat():
        stat_list.append(self.visit(s))
    node = ObjProg(stat_list)
    return node
```

The above code works fine. However, when I change the rule to this:

```
prog : s1=stat (',' s2=stat)* ;
```

what should be the corresponding visitor code? I tried writing it like this, but I am getting compilation errors:

```
def visitProg(self, ctx:ExprParser.ProgContext):
    stat_list = []
    stat_list.append(self.visit(ctx.s1))
    for s in ctx.s2:
        stat_list.append(self.visit(s))
    node = ObjProg(stat_list)
    return node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the rule:

```
prog : s1=stat (',' s2=stat)* ;
```

both `s1` and `s2` are single `stat` contexts. So the code `for s in ctx.s2` is not correct.

If you use the `+=` operator:

```
prog : stats+=stat (',' stats+=stat)* ;
```

then you could do:

```py
def visitProg(self, ctx:ExprParser.ProgContext):
    stat_list = []
    for s in ctx.stats:
        stat_list.append(self.visit(s))
    return ObjProg(stat_list)
```

And if there's a need to separate the first `stat` from the others, you could do this:

```
prog : first_stat=stat (',' stats+=stat)* ;
```

and then something like this:

```py
def visitProg(self, ctx:ExprParser.ProgContext):
    stat_list = [self.visit(ctx.first_stat)]
    for s in ctx.stats:
        stat_list.append(self.visit(s))
    return ObjProg(stat_list)
```

Perhaps you need to check if `ctx.stats is None`, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I made a minor edit in your answer to separate s1 and s2.

Comment: But there is no need to create 2 lists (`s1` and  `s2`). Besides, `s1` will always have just a single item, it doesn't make sense to create a llist from it with `+=`.